# Error with using other classes and compiling without main method

Tags: java, package

I have a `Game` class that extends the `JApplet` class and I want to be able to compile it but I also need to use my `Character` class.  The issue is that I have getting errors while compiling my `Character` class since I have no main method.  The errors on the compilation of the `Character` are this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Character (wrong name: kingdomofcarthania/Character)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
[Finished in 0.9s with exit code 1]
```

The errors when compiling the `Game` class are:

```
Game.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Character
location: package kingdomofcarthania
import kingdomofcarthania.Character;
                     ^
 Game.java:10: cannot find symbol
 symbol  : constructor Character()
 location: class java.lang.Character
    Character c = new Character();
                      ^
 Game.java:11: cannot find symbol
 symbol  : method resetCharacter()
 location: class java.lang.Character
    c.resetCharacter();
     ^
3 errors
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]
```

Here are some snippets of my Applet that might be helpful

`Game.java`

```
package kingdomofcarthania;

import kingdomofcarthania.Character;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends JApplet{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Character c = new Character();
    c.resetCharacter();
    }
}
```

`Character.java`

```
package kingdomofcarthania;

import kingdomofcarthania.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Character{
 private int xCoord;
 private int yCoord;
 private int currentZone;
 //private Map world;
 //private ArrayList<Zone> map;
 //private Inventory inventory;
 private int gold;

 //private ArrayList<Follower> followers;

 private int might;
 private int wisdom;
 private int dexterity;
 private int toughness;
 private int vigor;
 private int maxVigor;

 private int level;
 private int reputation;
 private int greatness;
 private int greatnessNeeded;

 private String title;


 public Character(){
 }

//some methods
}
```

I feel like I am making a silly mistake, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

These are the new errors I'm getting after changing some stuff:

```
Game.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Champion
location: package kingdomofcarthania
        kingdomofcarthania.Champion c = new kingdomofcarthania.Champion();
                      ^
 Game.java:9: cannot find symbol
 symbol  : class Champion
 location: package kingdomofcarthania
      kingdomofcarthania.Champion c = new kingdomofcarthania.Champion();
                                                          ^
 2 errors
```

Comment: How are you compiling this code?

Comment: Through Sublime Text 2, the standard way.

Comment: What is the standard way in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: This is the command:

{
 "cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""],
  "shell": true,
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java"
}

Comment: so problem is not with compilation (javac) but with execution (java)  ? i guess a problem of file path but i don't know Sublime Text 2, i wonder about file_regex and selector ...

Answer (score 0):

Your Character class is conflicting with **java.lang.Character**

Use explictly kingdomofcarthania.Character instead of just Character.

classes within **java.lang** package don't need import, so are subject to conflicts.

AND

You don't need to import class of the same package.

try removing

```
import kingdomofcarthania.Character;
```

and

```
import kingdomofcarthania.*;
```

Best Way would be to not create a Character class but a MyCharacter or KingDomCharacter to avoid naming conflict.

finaly see a related problem discussion here : http://www.coderanch.com/t/569181/java/java/class-conflicts

Comment: I made those changes and please look at my edit to the main post.